# Contador de horas progressivas e cumulativas com dias

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tenho um projeto onde devo acumular horas trabalhadas de um serviço em um projeto, ele deve armazenar no banco as horas/dias.

Então quando iniciado, se não houver tempo anterior começa do zero, mas se já houve uma etapa anteriormente ele deve contar a partir daquele e tempo e acumular, salvando depois no banco.

Até então o script está funcionando, porém preciso agora deixá-lo dinâmico para que o relatório apareça mais de um projeto mostrando o tempo de execução.

**JS**

```
<script language=JavaScript>
    <!-- begin
    function getSecs(sDias, sHors, sMins, sSecs, campo, tempo) {
        sSecs++;
        if (sSecs == 60) {
            sSecs = 0;
            sMins++;
            if (sMins <= 9) sMins = sMins;
        }
        if (sMins == 60) {
            sMins = 0;
            sHors++;
            if (sHors <= 8) sHors = sHors;
        }
        //converte para horas trabalhadas, se fossem dias normais seria 24h if(sHors==24){
        if (sHors == 8) {
            sHors = 0;
            sDias++;
        }
        //corrige com 2 digitos
        if (sSecs <= 9) sSecs = "0" + sSecs;
        if (sMins <= 9) sMins = "0" + sMins;
        if (sHors <= 9) sHors = "0" + sHors;
        if (sDias <= 9) sDias = "0" + sDias;
        document.getElementById(campo)
            .innerHTML = sDias + ":" + sHors + ":" + sMins + ":" + sSecs;
        setTimeout("getSecs(" + sDias + ", " + sHors + ", " + sMins + "," + sSecs + ", '" + campo + "')", 1000);
        form1.tempo.value = sDias + ":" + sHors + ":" + sMins + ":" + sSecs;
    }
    //-->
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    var_dump($_POST);
    $data1 = '0,1,59,55';
    $data2 = '0,7,59,55';
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<script>
    setTimeout("getSecs(<?= $data1 ?>, \"campo1\",'tempo;')", 1000);
</script>

<hr>

<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" name="form1">
    <input type="text" id="campo1" name="tempo" value="">
    <hr>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

Não entendo de js, mas creio que seja a melhor solução, achei um *script* interessante de *timer*, já adaptei algumas das necessidades, mas não consigo aplicar mais de um `input` fazendo o código reagir dinamicamente.

Comment: Achoq ue ficaria legal utilizando ajax, ai nem precisa do timer. 
Tambem aconselho você a utilizar a lib momentJs, facilita muito calculos com data.

Comment: Cara como faço isso? srsrsrsrsrrs

Comment: Manja trabalhar com ajax?

Comment: n.
Demorei 2 dias pra fazer uma junção de 4 scripts pra fazer isso rssrsr

Comment: Você conseguiu resolver?

Comment: ainda não consegui

Comment: Usa um plugin chamado [Final Countdown](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/). Meu colega precisou fazer exatamente a mesma coisa. Eu ensinei ele a fazer com o `LocalStorage` para armazenar onde o tempo "parou" para prosseguir posteriormente do mesmo ponto.

Comment: Foi mal, na verdade eu usei o plugin errado. O que ele usou chama `Flipclock`. Agora você já conhece dois :)

Comment: vou testar, vlw

Comment: Se resolveu o problema, pode fechar a pergunta.

Comment: Resolveu seu problema?

Answer (score 2):

Bem pessoal. Para fazer cálculos com horas, é preciso transformar a hora em um número que corresponde à menor unidade significativa com a qual vai trabalhar. Por exemplo, se precisar dos segundos, transforme-a em segundos: horaEmSegundos = horas*3600 + minutos*60 + segundos.
Aí calcule o tempo fazendo o cáculo tempoTotal = hrEmSegFinal - hrEmSegInicial.
Bem, desculpem, eu não entendo nada de PHP, eu comecei com Java e agora trabalho com NodeJS. Eu tenho, aqui, dois métodos em javascript, que no Java, logicamente, com pequenas adaptações, também funcionam. Acredito que seja possível também no PHP.
O primeiro pega a hora UNIX (todos os milissegundos desde 01/01/1970 somados) e calcula o intervalo de tempo. E só iniciar só ficar clicando nos botões parar/continuar que os intervalos de tempo vão sendo somados na variável tempo1Acumulado.
O Segundo, o cálculo e é feito a partir da hora digitada em campos de texto e estes intervalos vão sendo acumulados na variável tempo2Acumulado, em minutos. Ah, não esqueça, que este método visa ser simples e didático. Caso esse intervalo envolva a meia-noite(mudança de data), deve ser somado 24 horas à hora final(pode ser feito colocando um if se a hora de início é maior que a de término). Ah, por serem no javascript, podem apresentar problemas, se a hora da máquina cliente não estiver correta. Espero que possa ser adaptado ao PHP, mas no Nodejs funciona porque esta é a sua linguagem de programação.

HTML + JavaScript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
       <title>Contador acumulativo de tempo</title>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            tempo1Acumulado = 0; // Do 1o método: em milissegundos
            tempo2Acumulado = 0; // Segundo método: em minutos
            horaInicial;

            function setZero(num){ // põe zero a esquerda, se o numero for menor que 10.
                n = num.toString();
                   if(n.length < 2) {
                       n = "0" + n;
                    }
                    return n;
               }

            // msParaHora: Vai escrever o resultado no formato hh:mm:ss 
            function msParaHora(ms) {
                var horas = Math.floor(ms/3600000);    //  parte inteira da divisão
                var restoh = ms % 3600000;              //  resto da hora, em ms
                var minutos = Math.floor(restoh/60000);
                var restom = restoh % 60000;
                var segundos = Math.floor(restom/1000);
                return setZero(horas) + ":" + setZero(minutos) + ":" + setZero(segundos); 
            }
            /*Inicia a contagem do tempo*/
            function getHoraInicio(){ //Inicia a contagem 
                 horaInicial = Date.now(); 
                 $("#ta").text("Acumulado no inicio : " + tempo1Acumulado + " ms = " + msParaHora(tempo1Acumulado));
                 $("#info").text("Contagem em andamento...");
                 $("#btnIniciar1").prop("disabled", true);
                 $("#btnIniciar1").val("Continuar");
                 $("#btnFim1").prop("disabled", false);
            }
            /*suspende a contagem de tempo */
            function paraContador(){ //Termina a contagem do intervalo 
                 var horaFim = Date.now(); 
                 var intervalo = horaFim - horaInicial;
                 tempo1Acumulado += intervalo;

                 $("#info").text("duração do ultimo intervalo: " + intervalo);
                 $("#ta").text("Contagem Parada, Total acumulado:" + tempo1Acumulado 
                    + " ms = " + msParaHora(tempo1Acumulado));
                 $("#info").text("Duração do último intervalo: " + intervalo + "ms = " +
                       msParaHora(intervalo));
                 $("#btnIniciar1").prop("disabled", false);
                 $("#btnFim1").prop("disabled", true);

            }
            //*******Segundo Modo --- quando a hora é inserida manualmente *********************
            // **** O tempo é calculado em minutos, mas se por algum motivo precisar de 
            // mais precisão, basta adaptar os cálculos

            function minutosParaHora(minutos){
                var horas = Math.floor(minutos/60); // inteiro da divisão = horas
                var minuts = minutos % 60;      // resto da divisão = minutos
                return setZero(horas) + ":" + setZero(minuts);
            }

            function addTempo(){ // em minutos trabalhados
                var stri = $("#hIni").val(); // pega o valor do inicio
                var hrIni = stri.split(":"); // separa a hora dos minutos pelo ":", e coloca num array 
                // obter a hora de início, em minutos
                var hMinInic = parseInt(hrIni[0])*60 + parseInt(hrIni[1]);

                var strt = $("#hTerm").val(); // pega o valor do témino
                var hrTerm = strt.split(":"); // separa a hora dos minutos pelo ":", e coloca num array 
                // obter a hora de término, em minutos
                var hMinTerm = parseInt(hrTerm[0])*60 + parseInt(hrTerm[1]);

                var IntervaloDeTempo = hMinTerm - hMinInic;  // o Intervalo de tempo em minutos

                tempo2Acumulado += IntervaloDeTempo;       // adiciona este invervalo ao acumulado

               /*****************Exibe o resultado**/
               $("#ta2").text("Total Acumulado: " + tempo2Acumulado + " minutos = " 
                 + minutosParaHora(tempo2Acumulado) + ". Duração a última jornada: " 
                     +  IntervaloDeTempo + " minutos = " + minutosParaHora(IntervaloDeTempo));

             }

        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Contagem de Tempo</h1>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Método 1- A partir da hora do Sistema </legend>
                  <p id="ta">Total Acumulado: 0</p>
                  <p id="info">Clique no botão iniciar: 0</p>
                  <input id="btnIniciar1" type="button" value="Iniciar" onclick="getHoraInicio()" title="Iniciar neste momento"/>
                  <input id="btnFim1" type="button" value="Parar" onclick="paraContador()" title="Terminar agora" disabled="disabled"/>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Método 2- Apartir da hora digitada</legend>
                  <p id="ta2">Total Acumulado: 0</p>
                  <label>Hora Início</label>
                  <input type="text" id="hIni" value="14:17" /> <br/>
                  <label>Hora Término</label>
                  <input type="text" id="hTerm" value="17:30" /><br/>
                  <input id="btnCalc" type="button" value="Adicionar o Intervalo de Tempo" onclick="addTempo()" title="Terminar agora"/>
        </fieldset>
    </body>
</html>
```